# Syntax error in expression (error token is "INPUT (policy ACCEPT) | cut -d ' ' -f1)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, iptables

Hi I'am recently started learning bash scripts, since I'm quite "green" so to speak I hope I can get some help. I have this problem that I just can't seem to figure out on my own. I want this program to read through every line to check if there are any iptables rules for a given IP address. If there is: Take the number of the line, and then change or delete it with the iptables -R INPUT $lineNumberHere -s $IP_ADDRESS -j $newPolicy.

However the program starts reading the first lines and registers the line number as a "Chain" and "num" which causes the error. Is there a method of bypassing these two lines?

Just to clarify. I am running the program as root

```
# The IP address is listen in rules

        # Find the line number of the rule
        echo ""
        echo "The IP allready has a rule in iptables"
        iptables -L INPUT --line-numbers | while read line; do
                echo ""
                echo "Checking line: $line"
                LINE_NUMBER=$(($line | cut -d " " -f1))
                BANNED_IP=$(($line | cut -d " " -f4 | cut -d "/" -f1))
                re='^[0-9]+$'
                if [[ "$LINE_NUMBER" =~ $re ]]; then

                        echo "Line nr. $LINE_NUMBER"
                        if [ "$IP_ADDRESS"="$BANNED_IP" ]; then
                                echo "Changing status to BANNED"
                                iptables -R INPUT "$LINE_NUMBER" -s "$IP_ADDRESS" -j DROP
                        fi
                else
                        echo "error: Not a number" >&2
                        continue;

                fi

        done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several syntax problems in this script. In the lines:

```
 LINE_NUMBER=$(($line | cut -d " " -f1))
 BANNED_IP=$(($line | cut -d " " -f4 | cut -d "/" -f1))
```

...there are two problems: `$(( ))` evaluates its contents as an arithmetic expression, not as a command (that's why you're getting a "syntax error in expression" error). To run a command and capture its output, you want a single level of parentheses: `$( )` instead of `$(( ))`.

The other problem is with the command pipeline inside that rhe elements of a pipeline must be commands, and `$line` isn't one, it's just data. You want something like `$(echo "$line" | cut ...)`.

The other problem I see immediately is in this line:

```
if [ "$IP_ADDRESS"="$BANNED_IP" ]; then
```

you need spaces around the `=` operator; without them, it's not recognized as an operator at all, just part of a single long string. So use this instead:

```
if [ "$IP_ADDRESS" = "$BANNED_IP" ]; then
```

There may be other problems, these are just the ones that I spotted on inspection. BTW, I recommend [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) as an easy tool to point out common mistakes in bash scripts.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I'll try to run it first thing in the morning!

Answer (score 1):

While Gordon has answered the question you asked, I'd like to suggest an improvement. You don't need to run multiple `cut`s to parse this data, shell can do it fine. Also, since it's normal for two header lines of the `iptables` output to not contain line numbers, I would not output error messages that will alarm and confuse the user, just ignore (don't use) those lines:

```
iptables -L INPUT --line-numbers | while read ln _ _ ip _; do ip=${ip%/*} 
    if [[ $ln =~ ^[0-9]+$ && $ip = $IP_ADDRESS ]]; then
        echo Changing $IP_ADDRESS to banned
        iptables -R INPUT "$LINE_NUMBER" -s "$IP_ADDRESS" -j DROP
    fi
done
```

Note `[[ ]]` is special syntax and doesn't need variables quoted with `" "` although you can use them for consistency. But not on the regexp, because quoting the regexp makes it a literal match instead.

Comment: Double-quotes are also significant on the right side of an `=` comparison in a `[[ ]]` conditional expression -- without them, the right side is treated as a glob (wildcard) pattern, but with them it's treated as a literal string. In this case, the pattern-matching capability might actually be useful (e.g. `IP_ADDRESS='192.0.2.*'`) so leaving it unquoted makes sense -- but in that case the next two lines should use `$ip` instead of `$IP_ADDRESS` so they ban the specific ip address.